# How do I style an Angular component's nested CSS class?

Tags: css, angular

Let's say I have a simple Angular component here called `MyComponent`.

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: '[my-component]',
   template: `
      <div class="my-component-child">
         <ng-content></ng-content>
      </div>`,
   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
   host: { 'class': 'my-component' }
})
export class MyComponent {    
   constructor() { }    
}
```

This component is then used inside `ParentComponent`.

Because `MyComponent` encapsulation is set to none, I can style its `.my-component` class from within `ParentComponent` but I cannot style `.my-component-child` unless I set `ParentComponent` encapsulation to none, which I **prefer** to avoid.

How can I style `.my-component-child` or workaround it (without using root `styles.scss` or `::ng-deep` or parent's encapsulation set to none)?

If it's not possible to do the above with those conditions, are there any Angular practices or strategies that deal with this kind of situation (I'm still fairly new to Angular)?

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to pass CSS classes to the child component.
Your component will look like this:

```js
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: '[my-component]',
   template: `
      <div class="my-component-child" [ngClass]="extraClasses">
         <ng-content></ng-content>
      </div>`,
   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
   host: { 'class': 'my-component' }
})
export class MyComponent {    
   constructor() { }    
   @Input() extraClasses = ""
}
```

Then pass in extra classes to the child:

```html
<my-component [extraClasses]="flex"></my-component>
```

Of course, in this structure, you need to define the classes in the global context.

If you still don't want to declare any classes globally, then the other approach is to pass your desired options to the child and let the child component style itself based on the given options.